# Aligning Graphics and multiple lines

Tags: xetex, wrapfigure

I'm trying to align and image and some lines of text (not a paragraph) to resemble this.
[image]

this is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[10pt]{moresize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\definecolor{blu1000}{RGB}{15, 57, 101}
\definecolor{marrone1000}{HTML}{a4895e}
\definecolor{marronescuro1000}{HTML}{483a26}

\begin{document}            
\vspace*{-5\baselineskip}
\null\hfill {\color{marrone1000} \tiny Certificato d'iscrizione} \\ [\baselineskip]

\vspace*{2\baselineskip}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{img-1} \\ [\baselineskip]
\color{marrone1000}{
    \noindent\framebox[3cm][c]{\color{blu1000}\textbf{N. 1001-P}}
    \noindent\framebox[3cm][c]{\color{blu1000}\textbf{1001-P-YY-YY}} \\ [.15\baselineskip]
}
\raggedright \hspace{2.5em}\tiny \color{marrone1000}  Identification Number \hspace{5.7em}\tiny Certificate Number \\ [\baselineskip]
\centering
\color{blu1000}{
    \noindent\framebox[6cm][c]{\normalsize\color{blu1000}\textbf{Class Winner}} \\ [.15\baselineskip]
    \raggedright \hspace{5em}\tiny Category \\ [3\baselineskip]
}

\vspace{5\baselineskip}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.4\textwidth}
    \vspace{-24pt}
    \hspace{-14em}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{default_qrcode}
    % \vspace{-20pt}
\end{wrapfigure}

\textcolor{blu1000}{CERTIFICATE} \\ [2\baselineskip]
\color{marrone1000}{
    \noindent \rule{3cm}{0.4pt} \\ [0.15\baselineskip] \hspace{-6em}{Date of Issue \\ [2\baselineskip]}
    \noindent \rule{3cm}{0.4pt} \\ [0.15\baselineskip] \hspace{-6em}{Expiry Date\\ [2\baselineskip]}
}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Resulting
[image]

I'm using XeLatex and I'd like to left align the text as in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svFw9.png)

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please extend your code snippet to complete small document which we can test as it is. why do you use `wrapfigure`?

Comment: Hello, thanks @Zarko for the welcome. I've added the code of the page where it should be. I'm using wrapfigure because I wanted to align the image and text and after googling a lot, I was told that this was the correct way, but as you can see had to fix some spacing... would gladly remove that if I could do it better... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see if the following solution is acceptable to you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,          % <--- in real document delete option "showframe"
            a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{marrone1000}{HTML}{a4895e}

\usepackage[10pt]{moresize}
\usepackage[demo,               % <--- in real document delete option "demo"
            export]{adjustbox}  % <--- it load the graphicx package

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}\centering
    \includegraphics[height=2.5cm, width=\linewidth,valign=t]{img-1}
\end{minipage}
\quad
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}\raggedright
            CERTIFICATE         \\[1.5\baselineskip]
\tiny
\color{marrone1000}
\rule[-0.5ex]{\linewidth}{0.2pt}
            Date of issue:     \\[1.5\baselineskip]
\rule[-0.5ex]{\linewidth}{0.2pt}
            Expire date
\end{minipage}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

as you can see, i reduce your document example to mwe (minimal working example), which produce result similar to the first image in your question.

**edit:** for aligning of image in the first `minipage` it is necessary to move its baseline from its middle to the top. this is done by use of the `adjustbox` with option `export`. This package also load the `graphicx` package.

[image]

(lines around image and text shows page layout)

Comment: Awesome! thanks a lot, that's it. Most of the code you saw was because I just came into XeTeX from pure LaTex but I'm liking this more. Thanks again.